# Magento get TimeStamp not working well

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, time, datetime

I want to display a specific attribute only when the set time is not passed. 
Therefore I created the following code:

```
<?php $dateFrom = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp(); $dateTo = $_product->getData('actie_datum_eind');?>
<?php if (Mage::app()->getLocale()->isStoreDateInInterval($store, $dateFrom, $dateTo)) : ?>
    <div class="product-sale-label custom"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('actie_label')); ?></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

But does not work, the label is not displayed.

When I echo both values, I get the following results:

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('actie_datum_eind')?><br>
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp()?>
```

That results in the following:

```
2017-10-04 00:00:00
1505465811
```

The results of:

```
<?php echo $dateFrom?><br>
<?php echo $dateTo?>
```

Are:

```
1505465811
2017-10-04 00:00:00
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you please tell me what do you get in `$dateFrom` , `$dateTo` and `$store` ??

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Thanks, I just update my question with the values.

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2**

**Proper way**

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
/**
* @var TimezoneInterface
*/
protected $localeDate;

public function __construct(
    TimezoneInterface $localeDate
) {
   $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
}

$this->localeDate->isScopeDateInInterval($store,$FromDate,$ToDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but that does not seem to work. I am running Magento 1.9. I get a fatal error.

Comment: I think you recently mention that its for Magento 1.9. Let me update my answer. I already mentioned that its for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('actie_datum_eind') ?> //2017-10-04 00:00:00, your attribute value.

<?php $date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); ?> //2017-09-15 09:55:59, the actual date time.
```